# What does the .rf part of a .rpm filename mean?

Tags: rpm

I have an rpm file like `perl-Tidy-20071205-1.rf.noarch.rpm`.  What does the `.rf` part mean?

Comment: I just got a "Popular Question" badge for this "closed as off topic" question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means [**RPMForge**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPMforge).

> RPMforge now consists of more than one repository:
>
> ```
>   + rpmforge - packages that _do not_ replace base packages
>                (eg. nagios, wine, vlc, xine, mpg123, ...)
>   + rpmforge-extras - newer packages that _do_ replace base packages
>                       (eg. lftp, rsync, subversion, ...)
>   + rpmforge-testing - alternative test packages
>                        (eg. wine-1.3.x, ...)
>   + rpmforge-buildtools - packages required for building RPMforge pkgs
>                           (eg. bison, make, rpm-macros-rpmforge, ...)
>
> For convenience, packages belonging to one of the above repositories
> are tagged respectively with rf, rfx, rft and rfb distribution tags.
> ```

http://lists.repoforge.org/pipermail/users/2010-November/018282.html